# How to fix Upgrade Compatibility Tool Magento 2.4.5 errors

Tags: magento2, database, magento-upgrade, magento-connect

The following errors are showing in my custom module when generating report using **Upgrade compatibility tool.** in **2.4.5**

> Using class 'Magento\Company\Model\ResourceModel\Company\Collection'
> that is non API on version '2.4.5'
>
> Using class 'Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context' that is
> non API on version '2.4.5'
>
> Using class 'Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item' that is non
> API on version '2.4.5'

Please advise how to fix these issues?

Answer (score 0):

To fix "Using class that is non API on version '2.4.x'" and "Implemented interface that is non API on version '2.4.x'", mark that class as @api in docblock.

Example 1:

`Interface` before adding @api tag:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema;

/**
 * Marker interface for all types compatible with GraphQL schema generator.
 */
interface TypeInterface
{
}
```

After adding @api tag:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema;

/**
 * Marker interface for all types compatible with GraphQL schema generator.
 *
 * @api
 */
interface TypeInterface
{
}
```

Example 2:
`Class` before adding @api tag:

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Company;

use \VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractCollection;

/**
 * Company collection
 */
class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
}
```

After adding @api tag:

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Company;

use \VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractCollection;

/**
 * Company collection
 *
 * @api
 */
class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
}
```

Comment: Can you share me one example pls?

Comment: @NagarajuKasa I've updated my answer, please take a look. If you still need another example, feel free to let me know.

Comment: thank you for the answer. is there any alternative way to fix my above issue? pls advise

Comment: For magento core modules you should ignore it, for your module, you should apply the fix I mentioned above. I've also added another example.

Comment: I have followed this but not working in  Adobe Commerce ver. 2.4.5 is there any alternative way (or) other solution for the above issue ?

Comment: I think currently, it is a warning, not an error. So you can ignore these warnings. You can fix this issue for your custom modules and leave core modules for Magento to do.

Comment: Btw, I would like to confirm this solution should work, you can check the commit  to magento core: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/3ec2374d50b0bd85d51418b4070339fcdc8c84c5